# Hide a single field label

Tags: css, hide

I have one field label I want to hide using CSS if possible.

```
<div class="field-label">Text color:</div>
```

This is the CSS I tried to use,  but because of the way it is built, it hides all the field labels.

```
.product-designer .setting-field.half .field-label:first-of-type {
    display: None;
    }
```

How would I direct CSS to hide these elements specific to their name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inline CSS

```html
<h1 style = "display:none">I'm hidden</h1>
<h1>I'm not</h1>
```

Inline CSS will be prioritized over your stylesheets
Further reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#How_is_specificity_calculated)

Comment: Hi Alessandro and welcome to SO. Usually questions with explanation collects more reputation than questions with external links. I'll be happy if you can update your question with detauls from the link you provided.
Have a great day!